# Overflow on channel: flutter/lifecycle

Tags: flutter, dart, buffer

when I run my flutter application for the first time this message appears

> Overflow on channel: flutter/lifecycle.  Messages on this channel are
>   being discarded in FIFO fashion.  The engine may not be running or you
>   need to adjust the buffer size if of the channel.

the application is working normally but I don't know what is that message means or what it's effects

Answer (score 1):

Check which channel are you in by:

```
Flutter channel
```

If it is not stable, switch to stable channel.

```
Flutter channel stable
```

Comment: Thats not a very useful answer. A better answer would have been to link to the comment on the flutter issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41527#issuecomment-539105430 that points out that those log lines have been added recently and would only be in master/dev channel for now but are actually for an issue thats always been there and not something to be too worried about.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
flutter clean
flutter channel stable
```